# Rearchitecting SAS code

Tags: sas

Complete newbie to SAS here. Inherited a piece of code which I am tasked with re-architecting in SQL.

Going through the code and came across these 2 blocks which threw me off. Hoping someone here can help me interpret this or point out if my interpretation is correct?

```
 data A1;
 set temp2;
 newdate = datepart(saledate); -- Get day from saledate
 d1  = weekday(newdate);      --get weekday from the date part of saledate
 if d1 = 1 then d1 = 8;       --why is this?
 enddate = newdate + (8-d1)   --So enddate = newdate if its the first day of the week? Some kind of a date-difference here?
 format enddate date7.;       --what format is this? how does this output come out?
```

Then this block which I assume is doing some kind of aggregation:

```
  proc means data=A1 nway print;
  class col1 col2 enddate;
  var count;
  output out=A2(drop=_type_ _freq_)sum=;
  run;
```

What does sum=; mean? Where is the var count used? If no columns are provided for sum, what exactly is it aggregating here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
KV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's shifting the day to the end of the week (so, aggregating everything by week).  Weird way to do that, maybe it predates `intnx()`/`intck()` or `week()`.

The `sum=` means sum whatever is on the `var` list and save the sum in the same variable name (so `sum(count)=count` would be the same thing).  By leaving out the variable list on the left of = it means every variable, and by leaving out the to-be-named list means keep the names the same.

So basically, this sums up the `count` by week for each col1/col2 grouping.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the sum=

Comment: @user6754080 You may want to look at the SAS documentation at support.sas.com, it can be helpful.

Comment: @data_null_ Thanks. Yes, I am going over the documetation -thats how I could understand a lot of the code. I got thrown off by the sum=  which I couldn't find info on and some of the date conversions which I realised were specific to this program.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the code slightly so that we can see the results it produces for the past 30 days of dates:

**Test Code:**

```
data _null_;
  do newdate = date() -30 to date();
    d1  = weekday(newdate);      
    if d1 = 1 then d1 = 8;       
    enddate = newdate + (8-d1)   ;
    format newdate enddate date7.;       
    put newdate= d1= enddate=;
  end;
run;
```

**Output**:

```
newdate=25JUL16 d1=2 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=26JUL16 d1=3 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=27JUL16 d1=4 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=28JUL16 d1=5 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=29JUL16 d1=6 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=30JUL16 d1=7 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=31JUL16 d1=8 enddate=31JUL16
newdate=01AUG16 d1=2 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=02AUG16 d1=3 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=03AUG16 d1=4 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=04AUG16 d1=5 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=05AUG16 d1=6 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=06AUG16 d1=7 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=07AUG16 d1=8 enddate=07AUG16
newdate=08AUG16 d1=2 enddate=14AUG16
```

So we can see that the math is basically calculating the end of the week for the given date assuming that weeks start on Monday and finish on Sunday.  The good news is that there is a much simpler way to calculate this using the `intnx()` function and shift intervals. This approach can also be used within an SQL statement.

**Better:**

```
data _null_;
  do newdate = date() -30 to date();
    week_start = intnx('week.2', newdate, 0, 'beginning');
    week_end   = intnx('week.2', newdate, 0, 'end');
    format week_start week_end date7.;       
    put week_start= week_end=;
  end;
run;
```

The above code loops over the past 30 days.  For each date, it adds `0` weeks to the date, then returns either the beginning date of the week interval or the end date of the week interval.  We define our week as starting on Monday by using the a 'shift' of 2 (ie. `week.2` means, weeks start on Mondays instead of the default Sunday).

**Output:**

```
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=25JUL16 week_end=31JUL16
week_start=01AUG16 week_end=07AUG16
```

The `proc means` code basically translates to the following in SQL:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table a2 as 
  select col1, col2, enddate, sum(count) as count
  from a1
  group by 1,2,3
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Rob, good answer, but one thing we really are not supposed to do on Stack Overflow is directly do code conversion (as otherwise this ends up being an endless stream of requests like this).

Comment: @Joe Hmm, yes I completely forgot that when writing my answer.  I wonder if is still considered code conversion if it is within the same language?  Probably yes, because we don't want a whole bunch of data step -> sql questions or vice versa.... I was thinking about writing up an explanation similar to yours and figured that in the case given, it's almost a 1-to-1 mapping of keywords between `proc means` and `proc sql`, so it was easier to convey how it works simply by transforming the statement to sql.

Comment: I guess the point of no code conversion is that the question shouldn't be asking for the responder to do work for them - so yes, it's no better if it's in the same language.  (I suspect this is not - this is probably SQL Server or similar).  I try to stick very closely to simply explaining how the SAS works, as that's helpful for others.  I probably tend to be on the extreme end of this, though, but who knows.

Comment: Agreed @Joe. And as you can see I just asked if my interpretation is correct, not how to do it or for a sample. I wonder why StackOverflow blocked me from asking other questions based on this.

Comment: @user6754080 Your question was fine, I was specifically referring to the answer.  You have a -1 vote on the question (not mine) which by itself shouldn't block you, unless you have deleted some questions in the past.  You can ask on [meta] if you want more info as to why you're blocked (if you are).

Comment: Thanks for responding @Joe . I'll check out Meta. No, haven't deleted any questions in the past.